# How to access iframe from chrome extension while evading cross origin error

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I'm trying to access some page contents. In some websites they use inner iframe elements. When I try to access them (using `iframe.contentWindow.document` or `iframe.contentDocument`), I get an error `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame`. So is there a way to get to the inner elements of that iframe? Or do I need an extra permission or something in my extension?

Extension is **v3**

**permissions** `["storage", "tabs", "action", "gcm", "notifications"]`

**host_permissions** `["https://*/"]`

Comment: Extensions can't do it from the outside, but you can inject/declare the content script to run inside that iframe either by specifying all_frames in manifest.json or allFrames in executeScript.

Comment: Can you show me an example with executeScript?